# Unable to play recorded video and audio using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I’m trying to generate a video and audio for every 40ms in a separate files and sending it to the cloud for a live stream, but created videos and audio’s are unable to play using ffplay.

Command:

> ffmpeg -f alsa -thread_queue_size 1024 -i hw:0 -f video4linux2 -i
> /dev/video0 -c:a aac -ar 48k -t 0:10 -segment_time 00:00.04 -f segment
> sample-%003d.aac -c:v h264 -force_key_frames
> "expr:gte(t,n_forced*0.04)" -pix_fmt yuv420p -s:v 640x480 -t 0:10 -r
> 25 -g 1 -segment_time 00:00.04 -f segment frame-%003d.h264

Error:

> frame-001.h264: Invalid data found when processing input.

Console output:

> configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.2
> --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared   libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100   libavcodec     57.107.100 /
> 57.107.100   libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100   libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100   libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100   libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0   libswscale      4.  8.100 /
> 4.  8.100   libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100   libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100 Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.0 : stereo Input #0, alsa, from 'hw:0':   Duration: N/A, start:
> 1610338632.931406, bitrate: 1536 kb/s
> Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s Input #1, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video0':   Duration: N/A,
> start: 3405.427360, bitrate: 147456 kb/s
> Stream #1:0: Video: rawvideo (YUY2 / 0x32595559), yuyv422, 640x480, 147456 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc Stream
> mapping:   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (pcm_s16le (native) -> aac (native))
> Stream #1:0 -> #1:0 (rawvideo (native) -> h264 (libx264)) Press [q] to
> stop, [?] for help [alsa @ 0x55777d96fe00] ALSA buffer xrun. [segment
> @ 0x55777d983d80] Opening 'sample-000.aac' for writing Output #0,
> segment, to 'sample-%003d.aac':   Metadata:
> encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
> Stream #0:0: Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
> Metadata:
> encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 aac [libx264 @ 0x55777d98fa20] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 [libx264 @
> 0x55777d98fa20] profile High, level 3.0 [libx264 @ 0x55777d98fa20] 264
>
> - core 152 r2854 e9a5903 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2017 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=1 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00
>   mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0
>   deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6
>   lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0
>   bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=0 keyint=1
>   keyint_min=1 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc=crf mbtree=0 crf=23.0
>   qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00 [segment
>   @ 0x55777d98dda0] Opening 'frame-000.h264' for writing Output #1,
>   segment, to 'frame-%003d.h264':   Metadata:
>   encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
>   Stream #1:0: Video: h264 (libx264), yuv420p, 640x480, q=-1--1, 25 fps, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
>   Metadata:
>   encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 libx264
>   Side data:
>   cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1 [segment @ 0x55777d983d80] Opening 'sample-001.aac' for writing
>   [segment @ 0x55777d98dda0] Opening 'frame-001.h264' for writing
>   [segment @ 0x55777d98dda0] Opening 'frame-002.h264' for writing
>   [segment @ 0x55777d98dda0] Opening 'frame-003.h264' for writing
>   [segment @ 0x55777d98dda0] Opening 'frame-004.h264' for writing
>   [segment @ 0x55777d98dda0] Opening 'frame-005.h264' for writing
>   [segment @ 0x55777d98dda0] Opening 'frame-006.h264' for writingA dup=1
>   drop=0 speed=1.07x ...    [segment @ 0x55777d98dda0] Opening
>   'frame-018.h264' for writingA dup=5 drop=0 speed=0.714x  ...
>   [segment @ 0x55777d98dda0] Opening 'frame-029.h264' for writingA
>   dup=12 drop=0 speed=0.768x     ... [segment @ 0x55777d98dda0] Opening
>   'frame-042.h264' for writingA dup=21 drop=0 speed=0.834x     ...
>   [segment @ 0x55777d983d80] Opening 'sample-055.aac' for writingA
>   dup=31 drop=0 speed=0.89x     ... [segment @ 0x55777d98dda0] Opening
>   'frame-067.h264' for writingA dup=39 drop=0 speed=0.887x     ...
>   [segment @ 0x55777d98dda0] Opening 'frame-081.h264' for writingA
>   dup=49 drop=0 speed=0.92x     ... [segment @ 0x55777d98dda0] Opening
>   'frame-091.h264' for writingA dup=56 drop=0 speed=0.904x     ...
>   [segment @ 0x55777d98dda0] Opening 'frame-105.h264' for writingA
>   dup=66 drop=0 speed=0.927x     ... [segment @ 0x55777d98dda0] Opening
>   'frame-119.h264' for writingA dup=76 drop=0 speed=0.944x     ...
>   [segment @ 0x55777d98dda0] Opening 'frame-130.h264' for writingA
>   dup=84 drop=0 speed=0.938x     ... [segment @ 0x55777d98dda0] Opening
>   'frame-144.h264' for writingA dup=94 drop=0 speed=0.952x     ...
>   [segment @ 0x55777d983d80] Opening 'sample-154.aac' for writingA
>   dup=103 drop=0 speed=0.958x     ... [segment @ 0x55777d98dda0] Opening
>   'frame-168.h264' for writingA dup=111 drop=0 speed=0.952x     ...
>   [segment @ 0x55777d98dda0] Opening 'frame-182.h264' for writingA
>   dup=121 drop=0 speed=0.962x     ... [segment @ 0x55777d98dda0] Opening
>   'frame-193.h264' for writingA dup=129 drop=0 speed=0.956x     ...
>   [segment @ 0x55777d98dda0] Opening 'frame-207.h264' for writingA
>   dup=139 drop=0 speed=0.965x     ... [segment @ 0x55777d983d80] Opening
>   'sample-218.aac' for writingA dup=149 drop=0 speed=0.974x     ...
>   [segment @ 0x55777d98dda0] Opening 'frame-231.h264' for writingA
>   dup=156 drop=0 speed=0.964x     ... [segment @ 0x55777d98dda0] Opening
>   'frame-249.h264' for writing frame=  250 fps= 24 q=-1.0 Lsize=N/A
>   time=00:00:10.00 bitrate=N/A dup=168 drop=0 speed=0.98x
>   video:2707kB audio:149kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global
>   headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown [aac @ 0x55777d98cf00] Qavg:
>   260.500 [libx264 @ 0x55777d98fa20] frame I:250   Avg QP:26.77  size: 11085 [libx264 @ 0x55777d98fa20] mb I  I16..4: 13.4% 72.3% 14.3%
>   [libx264 @ 0x55777d98fa20] 8x8 transform intra:72.3% [libx264 @
>   0x55777d98fa20] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 54.2% 91.6% 64.5% [libx264 @
>   0x55777d98fa20] i16 v,h,dc,p: 13% 18%  6% 62% [libx264 @
>   0x55777d98fa20] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 19% 18% 16%  6%  7%  6%
>   12%  5% 10% [libx264 @ 0x55777d98fa20] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu:
>   28% 18% 11%  6%  8%  8% 10%  5%  6% [libx264 @ 0x55777d98fa20] i8c
>   dc,h,v,p: 58% 20% 15%  7% [libx264 @ 0x55777d98fa20] kb/s:2216.90

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `-f stream_segment` (or the alias `-f ssegment`). From the [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment):

> `stream_segment` is a variant of the `segment` muxer used to write to
> streaming output formats, i.e. which do not require global headers,
> and is recommended for outputting e.g. to MPEG transport stream
> segments. `ssegment` is a shorter alias for `stream_segment`.

Example command:

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -thread_queue_size 1024 -i hw:0 -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 -c:a aac -ar 48k -t 0:10 -segment_time 00:00.04 -f stream_segment sample-%003d.aac -c:v h264 -force_key_frames "expr:gte(t,n_forced*0.04)" -pix_fmt yuv420p -s:v 640x480 -t 0:10 -r 25 -g 1 -segment_time 00:00.04 -f stream_segment frame-%003d.h264
```

However, your output durations are so short you may have trouble playing them, but that's a completely different topic.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Now I'm able to see some video using ffplay, but with audio I have same issue. `Error: sample-000.aac: Invalid data found when processing input 0B f=0/0` `[mpegts @ 0x7f6f30000b80] Format mpegts detected only with low score of 2, misdetection possible!
[mpegts @ 0x7f6f30000b80] Could not detect TS packet size, defaulting to non-FEC/DVHS
sample-001.aac: could not find codec parameters`  and few samples play for long time like 13s.

Comment: I want these segments to be short because I’m sending it to AWS Kinesis Video Streams for a live video and audio stream. I have increased `-segment_time 0.08`, but I got same error.

Comment: @lloganI have downloaded and tried on latest 4.3.1 version, but facing same issue. I'm I missing to specify anything for audio in command?

Comment: @VijayRakesh Increase both instances of `-segment_time` until it works.

Comment: @IIogan Thanks for the continous support. I have tried increasing `-segement_time` up to 5s, but no change at the output. When I use ffplay on segment audio, it plays continuously more than 5s until I manually close it.

Comment: @IIogan any suggestions?

Comment: @VijayR Not really. I can't duplicate the problem using the same commands and same ffmpeg version, outputting to local files (no AWS). Works for me. How do I duplicate the issue? Why output 2 separate streams instead of both into 1? Why ADTS AAC and raw H.264 instead of MP4?

Comment: @IIogan I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.5 OS, FFMPEG 4.3.1 and Logitech C110 webcam. To make sure we both are running the same command I'm sharing the command `ffmpeg -f alsa -channels 1 -thread_queue_size 1024 -i hw:1 -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 -c:a aac -ar 48k -t 0:10 -segment_time 00:00.08 -f stream_segment sample-%003d.aac -c:v h264 -force_key_frames "expr:gte(t,n_forced*0.08)" -pix_fmt yuv420p -s:v 640x480 -t 0:10 -r 25 -g 1 -segment_time 00:00.08 -f stream_segment frame-%003d.h264` Kindly please let me know output on your side.

Comment: @IIogan Two output streams because AWS accepts audio and video files in separate with aac and h264 format, I'm trying to generate similar video and audio output files as provided in https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-producer-c/tree/master/samples

Comment: @IIogan I just tried to run only `ffmpeg -f alsa -channels 1 -i hw:1 -c:a aac -ar 48k -t 0:10 sample.aac ` when I play `sample.aac` using ffplay, it started to play which I have recorded and then it continued to play in silent until I manually stop it.

Comment: @VijayR `ffplay` does that by default. Add `-autoexit`.

Comment: Hi @IIogan, to set key frame interval as 45, I have set `-g 45` and removed `"expr:gte(t,n_forced*0.08)"`, but  ffmpeg is generating a few samples around 20 instead of 375. Am I making any mistake?

Comment: @VijayR You should ask as a new question. It's different enough from the original question that it should be a new question.

Comment: @IIogan Posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66118450/ffmpeg-couldnt-generate-all-segments-with-key-interval-value