# FFMPEG couldn't generate all segments with key interval value

Tags: ffmpeg

To set key frame interval as 45, I have set `-g 45` in below command, but ffmpeg is generated 20 video segments(sometimes even less) instead of 375 segments ((1000ms / 80ms) * 30s) for 30 seconds video with 25fps. Am I doing correct?

`ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 -c:v h264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -s:v 640x480 -t 0:30 -r 25 -g 45 -segment_time 00:00.08 -f stream_segment video-%003d.h264`

Comment: *a few samples around 20 instead of 375 for 30 seconds video with 25fps* --> unclear.

Comment: @Gyan Modified question.

Comment: ffmpeg splits segments at KF. 0.08 seconds is 2 frames but your KF interval is 45 frames,